# LIMIT CLAUSE With union

Tags: mysql

I have this kind of query. I am using limit, but this query gives me 20 results. Can anybody tell me why

```
SELECT 
    *,
    `tablename`.`bookmark_id` as `bookmark_id`,
    `tablename`.`bookmark_date` as `bookmark_date`  
FROM  ( (" + sql1 + ") 
UNION ALL (" + sql2 + ") 
UNION ALL (" + sql3 + ") ) AS tablename 
WHERE `bookmark_id` 
NOT IN 
   (SELECT `table1`.`bookmark_id` 
   FROM (
       (SELECT `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` 
        FROM `user_bookmarks` 
        WHERE `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` = `bookmark_id` 
        AND `user_id` = 26) 
        UNION 
       (SELECT `bookmark_id` 
        FROM `user_deleted_bookmarks` 
        WHERE `user_id` = ?)
       ) AS `table1`)  
GROUP BY bookmark_id 
ORDER BY `bookmark_date` 
DESC limit 17, 20
```

Thanks

Comment: how? i m saying limit 17,20

Comment: apologies, i read the question wrong.

Comment: i am expecting 4 results from above query. but it is showing 20

Comment: so you want results 17, 18 ,19 and 20 correct?

Comment: @FelixLahmer: then how i will display recodre frrm 17 to 20

Comment: yes, might be 1,2,3,4 then 5,6,7,8, and then 9,10,11,12 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SELECT docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

With one argument, the value specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of the result set:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5;     # Retrieve first 5 rows
```

With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

I think you want `LIMIT 16, 4`

Answer (score 1):

When you use limit, second argument is number of results to return.
See : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

In your case you want :

```
SELECT .... LIMIT 16,4
```

You will get 4 rows : 17, 18, 19 and 20.

Comment: u mean, he gets for rows after 16

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,`tablename`.`bookmark_id` as `bookmark_id`,`tablename`.`bookmark_date` as `bookmark_date`  FROM  ( (" + sql1 + ") union all (" + sql2 + ") union all (" + sql3 + ") ) AS tablename WHERE `bookmark_id` NOT IN (SELECT `table1`.`bookmark_id` FROM ((SELECT `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` FROM `user_bookmarks` WHERE `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` = `bookmark_id` AND `user_id` = 26) UNION (SELECT `bookmark_id` FROM `user_deleted_bookmarks` WHERE `user_id` = ?)) AS `table1`)  GROUP BY bookmark_id ORDER BY `bookmark_date` 
DESC limit 16, 4;
```

for getting result 17,18,19,20
it's count start from 17th position and give next 4 values